# Is the kanji for sister-in-law and step sister the same?

Tags: kinship-terms

I was wondering if the kanji for both sister-in-law and step sister is 義妹 (younger sister) or 義姉 (older sister) and there's no way of differentiating them other than context?

Comment: Why do you ask specifically for female siblings rather than either female or male siblings?

Comment: Because when I come across machine translation, it always translates 義 to in-law but by context it means step-siblings, hence the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your question is how to tell meaning of 義姉, you need to guess from contexts in the present-day colloquial language.

Strictly speaking, [義]{ぎ}[姉]{し} or [義]{ぎ}[妹]{まい} only means (or meant) sister-in-law or sworn sister.  Here are definitions in デジタル大辞泉.

> ぎ‐し【義姉】
>
> １ 義理の姉。妻または夫の姉、兄の妻など。
>
> ２ 血縁関係はないが、姉妹の約束を交わして姉としている人。

> ぎ‐まい【義妹】
>
> １ 義理の妹。夫または妻の妹、弟の妻など。
>
> ２ 血縁関係はないが、姉妹の約束を交わして妹としている人。妹分。

In colloquial language, [義]{ぎ}[姉]{し} and [義]{ぎ}[妹]{まい} have taken in the place of [継]{まま}[姉]{あね} and [継]{まま}[妹]{いも} which mean elder/younger stepsister.

If your question is how to distinguish step sister from sister-in-law, you can use [異]{い}[母]{ぼ}[姉]{し} (elder sister from a different mother), [異]{い}[父]{ふ}[姉]{し} (elder sister from a different father) and so on, which sound very formal.

Comment: Does that mean colloquially 継姉 and 継妹 are just less used compared to 義姉 and 義妹?

Comment: Yes.  I have never heard 継姉 and 継妹 in daily conversation and I found many people use 義姉 and 義妹 instead, although I think people can understand 継姉 and 継妹 when they hear them by analogy with 継母, which is sometimes used in fairy tales.

Comment: I think it's because using 継 (2 syllable) is longer than using 義 (1 syllable). Anyway thanks for the explanation!